# crawl content of currently opened gmail message

Tags: javascript, gmail

I need to parse the content that is in the gmail message but only of those gmail message which is currently opened not the whole documents. For example, if we open the gmail in such url format

`https://mail.google.com/mail/u/1/#inbox/164a1b634b58699f`

which is the page of particular message not the whole body of gmail.

For parsing the content i used the treewalker as follow

```
var scriptFilter = {
  acceptNode: function(node) {
    if (node.parentNode.nodeName !== 'SCRIPT' || node.parentNode.nodeName !== 'STYLE') {
      return NodeFilter.FILTER_ACCEPT;
    }
  }
};



var walker = document.createTreeWalker(
  document.body, 
  NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT, 
  scriptFilter, // only needs the pure content from currently opened gmail message body
  false
);

var node;
var textNodes = [];

while(node = walker.nextNode()) {
  textNodes.push(node.nodeValue);
}

console.log(textNodes);
```

This parses the content of whole documents but i need to parse only on the currently opened gmail messages body.

Only the body part of currently opened gmail message like in screenshot

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I think it would be much easier (and cleaner) to use the gmail api to read the message
https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/get

Comment: can you show just a sample so it can be accepted as answer, please?